# Time execution VBA SUB-SUB with IRibbonControl

Tags: excel, vba, ribbon

I have a problem of time in the execution of my sub.
As an example the following code. If I execute it from VBA Editor it takes 4 seconds, but if I call it from a custom button in the Ribbon using: Public Sub test_sub(control as IRibbonControl) it takes 66 seconds. I don´t understand why..

```
'SUB executed from VBA editor:

Public Sub test_sub()

Dim i As Integer

Dim t As Double

t = Timer

For i = 0 To 20

    Call generar_resumen

Next i

Debug.Print " tiempo sub = " & Timer - t

End Sub


'SUB executed from button in Excel Ribbon:

Public Sub test_sub(control as IRibbonControl)

Dim i As Integer

Dim t As Double

t = Timer

For i = 0 To 20

    Call generar_resumen

Next i

Debug.Print " tiempo sub = " & Timer - t

End Sub
```

Please, anyone could help me? I don´t know what to do.

Thanks

Comment: Any information what `generar_resumen` is doing? And maybe this is a question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: the sub copies cells from one Excel sheet to a new one.
I made some controls and if you only delete "control as IRibbonControl" you speed up the excecution of the sub

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Storax While this may be on-topic on CR in the future, please don't use the existence of the Code Review site as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *needs focus*, *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Then you can mention to the OP that it can be posted on Code Review if it is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please see [_Does being on-topic at another Stack Exchange site automatically make a question off-topic for Stack Overflow?_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287400/1575353)

Comment: Thanks for the hint I still think it belongs on CR and should be closed here as according to the OP the code is only slow only if he calls it from the Ribbon and he already applied the usual trick with turning off event, calculation etc. And as mentioned in the link I did not VTC automatically. But, of course, you can have a different opinion.

Comment: Please, I don´t mind to move the question if you think i could get some additional help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try to use this at start:

```
 On Error GoTo Err_Exit:
 Application.EnableEvents = false
 Application.ScreenUpdating = false
```

And at end you can use this again to enable it

```
 Err_Exit:
 Application.EnableEvents = true
 Application.ScreenUpdating = true
```

Comment: In the sub "generar_resumen" I have already considered:
With Application

    .EnableEvents = False

    .ScreenUpdating = False

    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    .DisplayAlerts = False

End With

so in both cases, all it´s the same. The only change between both subs is that they are called from a button or not
Thanks